# How expensive are extra references in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find out how expensive references in JS. An alternative to adding many references to existing objects, would be to use 1 ES6 Proxy, and then source the would-be references, dynamically. If you are unlikely to use the references, then using a Proxy might be more performant (that's my theory, but I'd like to find out).

say we have 5 existing objects:

```
const foo1 = {}, foo2 = {}, foo3 = {}, foo4 = {}, foo5 = {};
```

then we have another new object:

```
const bar = {};
```

we could add references to the foos, like so:

```
bar.foo1 = foo1;
bar.foo2 = foo2;
...
bar.foo5 = foo5;
```

or, we could use a Proxy, like so:

```
bar.proxy = new Proxy();  // we could actually re-use an existing proxy object to source the foo objects
```

and then `bar.proxy` could dynamically source the foo objects.

The question is, which is more performant? How could we measure it?

Comment: for example, instead of tacking on a bunch of references, I was thinking about using a single ES6 Proxy property on `a`,`b` and `c`, and using the ES6 Proxy to source objects instead.

Comment: what is the difference between reference and creating a new object in your case? New objects will also be referenced by a, b and c, so it is all reference

Comment: How expensive is reference? negligible. Requires virtually no memory and no processing vs new object

Comment: @smnbbrv the difference is monumental. References refer to the same object so changing one changes all.

Comment: @earthling how is what you are saying connected to the OP's question? The question is about performance, not about what gets changed

Comment: @smnbbrv my comment was in response to yours since you said no difference. But there's also a difference in performance. Recreating an object both occupies more memory and takes more computation.

Comment: yeah, like I said, say I have to add 15 references to existing objects `a`, `b`, and `c`, versus adding one new proxy object to `a`,`b`, and `c` ....Which is better 1 new Proxy object, or 15 references to existing objects. I don't know how to measure how expensive references really are.

Comment: @earthling ok, you totally misunderstand what I told. The critical part here is `in your case`. Please read carefully. Anyway this question is doomed, I quit it right now

Comment: @AlexanderMills I'm afraid your question is not very clear. Maybe more specific code may help clarify.

Comment: Ok I will update it, to make it more specific

Comment: I dramatically updated the question to make it more specific. There's a simple choice between using a single Proxy object vs. using X number of references. In the example, it's 5, but I am wondering how big X could be, before using a Proxy might be more efficient.

Comment: the question ultimately just about how expensive references to existing objects are.

Comment: And the answer is references are still negligible since they point to same memory location

Answer (score 2):

You should use as many references as you need. One reference is 4 bytes of memory. Proxy class is ment to be used to proxy classes and not to save memory.
Code quality is a very important factory and doing non-standard optimizations will be at cost of quality.
And at the same time how would you ever save any memory using proxy? if you are to initialize a proxy you need the object reference. If you have the reference you dont need proxy to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, references aren't expensive. If anything, they are the exact opposite.

In terms of whether you would use a reference or clone/create an object, it really depends on your use-case. If you clarify your use-case, I'll update my answer with a better recommendation as to whether you should use references or not.

Comment: this should be a comment, a promise to update the answer when the question becomes clear is not an answer

Comment: @smnbbrv I have already answered his question in the first line.

Comment: I am asking him to improve his question for a better response.

Comment: no, you did not answer the question, because you did not understand it, because the author of the question did not clarify it yet. Your answer is exactly what you say as two first words: **generally speaking**. Generally speaking, the answer for any stackoverflow question could be 42

Comment: not sure what your problem is.... i'm trying to help this person and you are just constantly arguing with me about nonsense. No wonder people get sick of the toxic atmosphere here on SO.